$rank(C-AB)+n=rank(D-BA)+m$ imples $C=kI, D=kI$?

Let $C$ be a $m\times m$ matrix, $D$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. If for any $A_{m\times n}, B_{n\times m}$ we have $rank(C-AB)+n=rank(D-BA)+m$, show that $C=kI_m, D=kI_n$ for some $k$

What is the idea? the converse statement is easy by Schur complement method.
Let $A=0, B=0$, then $rank C+n=rank D+m$. ...
By Schur complement method, $rank\begin{pmatrix}I_n&B\\
A&C\end{pmatrix}=rank(C-AB)+n=rank(D-BA)+m=rank\begin{pmatrix}D&B\\
A&E_m\end{pmatrix}$
How to choose useful $A,B$?

The assertion is trivial when $m=n=1$ (and $k$ may be zero). Suppose $m\ge\max(n,2)$ and $n\ge1$. We shall show that $C=kI_m$ and $D=kI_n$ for some nonzero scalar $k$.
The rank condition in question is equivalent to
$$
\operatorname{nullity}(C-AB) = \operatorname{nullity}(D-BA)
\quad\text{for all $A$ and $B$}.\tag{1}
$$
Note that $C$ and $D$ must be nonzero. Suppose the contrary. By putting $A$ into $(1)$, we see that $C$ and $D$ have the same nullity. Since $m\ge n$, if at least one of $C$ and $D$ is zero, we must have $D=0$ and the nullity of $C$ is $n$. Now, if $m=n\ge2$, then $(1)$ is violated by any $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=0\ne BA$. If $m>n\ge1$ instead, pick any nonzero vector $x\in\operatorname{range}(C)$ and also any row vector $y^T$ such that $y^Tx\ne0$. Pad $x$ and $y^T$ with zero columns/rows to form $A$ and $B$ respectively. As $x\in\operatorname{range}(C)$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(C-AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(C)$ and $\operatorname{nullity}(C-AB)\ge\operatorname{nullity}(C)=n$. However, as $y^Tx\ne0$, $BA$ is rank-one. Therefore $\operatorname{nullity}(BA)=n-1<n\le\operatorname{nullity}(C-AB)$ and we arrive at a contradiction.
Now, by $(1)$, for any invertible matrix $P$, we have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{nullity}(C-AB)
&=\operatorname{nullity}(D-BA)\\
&=\operatorname{nullity}(D-BP^{-1}PA)\\
&=\operatorname{nullity}(C-PABP^{-1}).\\
\end{align*}
In particular, when $A$ and $B$ are rank-one matrices, we obtain
$$
\operatorname{rank}(C-uv^T)=\operatorname{rank}(C-Puv^TP^{-1}).\tag{2}
$$
Therefore $C$ must be invertible, or else $(2)$ is violated by picking any $u$ outside the column space of $C$, any $v^T$ outside the row space of $C$, and any invertible matrix $P$ that maps $u$ into the column space of $C$ (such $P$ exists because $C\ne0$).
It follows from $(2)$ that $\det(C-uv^T) = 0$ if and only if $\det(C-Puv^TP^{-1})=0$. In turn, $v^TC^{-1}u = 1$ if and only if $v^TP^{-1}C^{-1}Pu = 1$. Therefore $C^{-1}=P^{-1}C^{-1}P$ for every invertible matrix $P$. Consequently, $C$ commutes with every invertible matrix $P$. Hence $C=kI_m$ for some scalar $k$. As $C$ is invertible, $k$ is nonzero.
By a similar argument, we also have $D=k'I_n$ for some $k'\ne0$. If we put $A=\pmatrix{kI_n\\ 0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{I_n&0}$, then $(1)$ gives $n=\operatorname{nullity}((k'-k)I_n)$. Therefore $k=k'$.
